# Git rebase approach to avoid duplicate commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

There is strange issue I am facing when I am trying to do the rebase into my development branch from master. There is some work in progress in the master as well as in dev branches.

In order to get the changes from master I do below

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

This works fine. But -

1. The `dev` branch commits are duplicating when I do

   `git checkout dev
   git add .
   git commit -m 'some change'
   git push
   git rebase master`

   the commit`some change` is repeating in git project history for dev branch. It also creates the loop .
2. If I do `git rebase master` before pushing the dev branch changes then it works well and I can see linear history in project.

I am not sure why it is like that. This seems to me the strange behaviour. Please help if anyone can explain this.

**Project History** 
commit `b48659d` is duplicating(original commit I did `37c07a4`) when first did push and then rebase in dev branch.

```
*   fbadb86 (HEAD -> dev) Merge branch 'dev' of *******
|\  
| * b48659d (origin/dev) sample added in dev branch --> did rebase after push and got this commit again
* | 37c07a4 sample added in dev branch --> commit + push
* | 46c1f40 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) master file added in master branch --> commit + push
|/  
* 5baae80 first commit
```

And this happens for all commits after doing the push. That is causing lots of issue in rebasing as the commits are repeating and also creating lot off conflicts even with my own code changes from previous commits.

Comment: No matter rebase before pushing or after push, the commit history should be linear. Did you make changes on `master` branch after first time rebasing? And what's the commit history graph now (`gitk --all`)?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT, I have added the project history, please check.

Comment: Which commit(s) is the rebased commit for the first time? the commit history can't find the manner for the first time rebasing. And what if you use `git push -f origin dev` to push dev branch?

Comment: What do you mean by _There is some work in progress in the master as well as in dev branches._?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*All* commits are read-only, always.  They are also permanent, with some exceptions (having to do with whether anyone can *find* them).  This means that `git rebase` *copies* commits.  That's it's job!

Let's take a look at your `git log --graph --oneline ...` output, but let's start a bit simpler:

```
  * b48659d (dev) ...
* | 46c1f40 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) ...
|/
* 5baae80 first commit
```

Note the shortened hash IDs, such as `5baae80` and `b48659d`.  These are the "true names" of each commit, shortened to just 7 characters since that's usually sufficient.<sup>1</sup>  Each commit records the ID of a *parent* commit, and Git uses these parent commit hashes to follow each commit backwards through history, starting from a more-recent *branch tip* commit.  The tip commit of branch `dev` is now `37c07a4...`:

```
5baae80--46c1f40   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        b48659d   <-- dev
```

None of these commits can ever be changed!

You now `git push` this to `origin`.  The `git push` command calls up a second Git, over on the machine acting as `origin`, and hands over the commits that you have that they don't, which everyone agrees to by their IDs.  Then your Git asks their Git to set their `dev`, which will be your `origin/dev`, to the same value as your `dev`: `b48659d...`  If they agree to this request, your Git remembers that they now have *their* `dev`—your `origin/dev`—pointing to `b48659d`, just as we have drawn here, so now we have this:

```
5baae80--46c1f40   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        b48659d   <-- dev, origin/dev
```

At this point, you run `git rebase`, and this is where things start to go wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git now dynamically chooses the shortened length, rather than just always using 7, but it starts with 7 by default.  You can always use more: the full names are currently 40 characters long.

---

#### Rebase copies commits, then moves a branch label

The `git rebase` command cannot change any existing commit, because *nothing* in Git can do that.  Git is designed to make this impossible.  So it does not even try.  Instead, it *copies* commits.

When copying commits, Git needs two pieces of information:

- What commits should it copy?
- Where should it place the copies?

Git gets the first—the list of commits to copy—by listing commits starting from `HEAD` and working backwards, stopping at some point you choose.  (This list is backwards so it has to reverse it.)  Git gets the second—the target "copy after" point—from the argument you give it, such as `master`.

In this case, `HEAD` names `dev` (because you run `git checkout dev` before you start the rebase), so the commits to copy end with the one to which the name `dev` points:

```
5baae80--46c1f40   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        b48659d   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/dev
```

We will therefore copy some series of commits stopping at `b48659d`.

The place to copy them comes from your argument `master`.  The name `master` identifies commit `46c1f40`, so the copies will go after `46c1f40`.

The tricky part is how Git computes which commits *not* to copy.  It does this by starting from `b48659d` and working backwards.  You can imagine Git coloring each of these commits green temporarily.  This takes Git to `5baae80`, which has *no* parent commit (it is the first commit in the repository, so it cannot have a parent).  This stops the walk, so that these two commits are painted green.  Then Git starts from the commit you specified by name—`46c1f40`—and painting the commits red temporarily.  The parent of `46c1f40` is `5baae80`, so Git paints this one red (don't copy), and tries to go on to its parent to paint those red as well.  There is no parent, so we're done with the temporary painting, leaving one green commit, `b48659d`.

This is the list of commits to copy.  (It's backwards, but it's only one entry long anyway, so reversing it does nothing.)

Now Git begins the copying process.  Each commit to be copied is copied as if by `git cherry-pick` (if you use `git rebase -i`, it's literally copied by cherry-pick).  This makes *new* commits.

The new commit made from the existing `b48659d` is `37c07a4`.  Let's draw it in:

```
                 37c07a4
                /
5baae80--46c1f40   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        b48659d   <-- dev, origin/dev
```

Now that the entire list of commits has been copied, `git rebase` does one last thing.  It yanks the name `dev` off the original string of commits, and pastes it onto the new copy.  The result is:

```
                 37c07a4   <-- dev (HEAD)
                /
5baae80--46c1f40   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        b48659d   <-- origin/dev
```

You can see this in the `git log --graph` output you quoted in your question.

#### Where did the last commit come from?

The one remaining question is, where did this come from:

```
*   fbadb86 (HEAD -> dev) Merge branch 'dev' of *******
```

That commit exists because you ran `git merge`.

You probably ran `git merge` by running `git pull`.  What `git pull` does, by default, is run `git fetch` for you, and then run `git merge` for you.  (I advise beginners in Git never to use `git pull` at all: what it does, and the way it does it, is excessively confusing.  Split it up into `git fetch` followed, sooner or later, by a second Git command, sometimes `git rebase`, sometimes `git merge`.)

What `git merge` does, in general, is to try to combine two separate "lines of development".  Given a graph like this:

```
                 37c07a4   <-- dev (HEAD)
                /
5baae80--46c1f40
       \
        b48659d   <-- origin/dev
```

Git thinks, more or less, that someone else wrote `b48659d` (`origin/dev`) while you wrote `37c07a4`.  In order to *combine* them, Git finds their "merge base", which is where these two lines join up again.  Following the lines by eye makes it clear: that's `5baae80`.  So Git makes a new *merge commit*, which is a commit with *two* parents.  Let's draw that in:

```
                 37c07a4--fbadb86   <-- dev (HEAD)
                /         /
5baae80--46c1f40         /
       \       __--------
        b48659d   <-- origin/dev
```

This is what you see now, in your `git log --graph --oneline ...` output (with the `master` and `origin/master` arrows also added in—I left them out because they're just too hard to draw this way).

The fundamental error here was in running `git rebase` on commits that *someone else already had*.  In this case, the other Git over at `origin` already had commit `b48659d`.  You cannot change that commit, so when you make your new copy, you stop using *your* `b48659d`, but they still have theirs.  Eventually you have to incorporate "theirs" back with "your copy", by merging, giving this rather messy picture.

(There is an exception to this rule: if you can convince *everyone else* who has `b48659d` to give it up, and switch their `dev`s to use your new copy instead, you can still rebase.  But whether you can, and how, is another question.)

Comment: The hero we need but don't deserve

Comment: This really answered all my questions about git internals, thanks