# How to force git to re-use existing commit sha1 from non-abandoned branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Suppose we had (Z is a merge commit):

```
...--o--A--C            <-- master
        |\
        | --B           <-- branch
         \   \   
          ----Z         <-- develop
```

After `git checkout branch; git rebase master` and some commiting

```
             B¹-D       <-- branch            
            /         
...--o--A--C            <-- master
        |\
        | --B           
         \   \   
          ----Z         <-- develop
```

Then develop need to be updated: `git checkout develop; git rebase master --rebase-merges`

```
             B¹-D       <-- branch            
            /         
...--o--A--C            <-- master
        |\ |\
        || | --B²
        ||  \   \
        ||   ----Z²     <-- develop
        | \
        |  -B
         \   \   
          ----Z         [abandoned]
```

If I merge "branch" into "develop", history will contain both B¹ and B². Is it possible to ask git to detect that equal to B² commit already exists in non-abandoned branch "branch" and to re-use it?

Comment: Ah, the velocyraptor graph... we meet again (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/6309 from 2010)

Comment: No. `B¹` and `B²` are not equal, they're different because their parents are different. `git` calculates commit's IDs using a lot of information including parents' IDs.

Comment: @phd A is a parent of B but C is a parent of both B¹ and B².

Comment: @Lichtgestalt Then there're other differences — author/committer names and dates.

Comment: @phd Both B¹ and B² were made from B by `git rebase master` but in different branches ("branch" and "develop"). They have the same comment, author, date, body - everything except of sha1 (at least properties shown by `git log --graph`).

Comment: @Lichtgestalt `git rebase` changes committer date. Compare `git show -s --format=fuller` for B¹ and B².

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to add any [option like `--rebase-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309) *before* the branch you are rebasing onto.

```
git rebase --rebase-merges master
```

Then consider rebasing `develop` onto `branch` instead of `master`: `branch` already include `B1`, and `B2` won't be repeated.
In an *interactive* rebase (`-i` option), you will have the opportunity to *drop* `D` (a commit from `branch` you do not want in develop): that might work if there is just one of two commits specific to `branch` and not on `develop`. If the history is more complex, that would be cumbersome.
The end result would be `B1-Z'` on your new rebased `develop`, reusing `B1` as requested.

The key idea is, as [torek explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408982/6309):

- `git rebase` copies commits, then moves a branch label
- [`git rebase` won't duplicate a commit with the same content](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description)

That is:

> Note that any commits in `HEAD` which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in `HEAD..<upstream>` are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

That is why `B` would not be repeated as `B2`, and `B1` would be preserved/reused, even though their parent commits (of `B` and `B1`) and timestamps differ.